# jQuery count to number with duration between digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am looking to do is have a number start counting either up or down, lets say from 1 to a 100 or a 100 to 1. I have found many many plugins that do this but they all have a duration variable. The problem is that duration variable applies to how long it takes to get from start to finish. I am looking for a way to set how long it takes to get to the next digit. IE counting from X to Y and updating the number every .25 seconds. This way a larger number would take longer to get to than a smaller number.

This plugin looks great but I can't get it to do what I want.
https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo

Any help would be great.

Comment: Seems easy enough just to do it yourself with [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

Comment: @Tasos I know the plugin is amazeballs. Although you did make me think of an potential answer to my own question. I could calculate the duration variable on the fly based on the difference between the start and stop numbers. IE 25-225 would be 200 then divide by .25 seconds and that would give you your duration of 800. The bigger the number the the longer the duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```js
function count(target, start, end, step, timeInterval) {
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    
    
    if (start == end) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      return false;
    }    
    start += step;
    target.html(start);
  }, timeInterval);
}   
 
count($('#timer1'), 1, 100, 1, 50);
count($('#timer2'), 100, 1, -1, 50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer1"></div>
<div id="timer2"></div>
```

Comment: This answer workers better than the one below because it can go up or down and feels a bit cleaner. Although the myInterval var doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this and let me know if that's what you want:

```js
function countTo(min, max, interval, callback) {
 var counter = min;
    var i = setInterval(function() {
     callback(counter);
        counter++;
        if(counter> max) return clearInterval(i);
    }, interval*1000);
};


countTo(0, 100, 0.25, function(counter) {
 $("#counter").text(counter);
});
countTo(0, 100, 0.01, function(counter) {
 $("#counter2").text(counter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter"> </div>
<div id="counter2"> </div>
```